# Can't display notifications from service

Tags: android, android-studio, service, notifications

I have a problem with android studio. I can't display notifications from service, when I close th main app. Is there any way to do that?

This is my app:
It shows notification with 15 sec countdown

Main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View V) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyActivity.class);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("Text of notification")
            .setTicker("Notify");

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addParentStack(NotifyActivity.class)
            .addNextIntent(intent);

    PendingIntent pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(0, builder.build());

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(i);
}
```

MyService

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
public MyService() {
    super("MyWorkThread");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
                int time = 15 - i;
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, NotifyActivity.class);

                final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Time left: " + time)
                        .setContentText("Text of notification");

                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                        .addParentStack(NotifyActivity.class)
                        .addNextIntent(intent1);

                PendingIntent pIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

                nm.notify(0, builder.build());
                wait(1000);
            }
            nm.cancel(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aaaaand it's gone!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

NotifyActivity

```
public class NotifyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notify);
}
```

}

Service in AndroidManifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: Post your code so far to save down votes!

Comment: Where's your code?  See [ask]